# What is the name of the sub-field within spacial Data Science where the data relates in some way to physical objects viewed as 3D (graphics) Models?

Tags: visualization, data-analysis

What is the name of the specialism / sub-field in spacial Data Science where the data relates in some way to physical objects viewed as 3D (graphics) models?, ... that is, excluding GIS and BIM systems. One such example being when applied to the analysis of 3D models of machine parts created by CAD systems in Engineering, where Data Analytics and Data Visualisation may be applied to data arising from that analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* possible answers to this question.

Data science applied to [mechatronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechatronics) and [cybernetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybernetics) can involve [physical information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_information), which I believe is what you are describing. The DS side of mechatronics often involves [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) and [engineering cybernetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_cybernetics) principles. More specific sub-fields include [design optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_optimization) and [control theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory).

Edit to add a few more examples:

- [Fault detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_detection_and_isolation#Fault_detection_and_diagnosis_using%20artificial%20intelligence)
- [Anomaly Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection)
- [Simulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation#More_examples_of_simulation)

  - [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#Engineering)
- [Modeling and Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modeling_and_simulation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BenjiAlbert. Do you perhaps have any other suggestions to add to the list? What about areas of Data Science relating to  manufactured or engineered 3D parts / structures or designs e.g. the analysis of data gathered from testing how a proposed car or aeroplane model performs in certain conditions

Comment: @nicciglen I added a few more examples

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenjjAlbert. I appreciate your contribution. Though unfortunately I can't vote up your answer as I don't have enough SO points yet. :( Hopefully someone else does

Comment: @nicciglen not a problem! If you ever solve your problem, you can post your answer and accept your own solution btw. gl!